# How to get max value from a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an MYSQL database table of student info and their test scores per subject and I am trying to fetch each student's highest score in all subjects using the SQL query below

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    subject_id,
    (SELECT 
            MAX(score)
        FROM
            cbt_attempts_tbl
        WHERE
            first_name = first_name) AS MAX_SCORE
FROM
    cbt_attempts_tbl
WHERE
    score IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY first_name DESC
```

[sample data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1smioI-oYBsTD-hhRn8dhRGWrAKWIc9-g/view?usp=sharing)

After running the query, the result I get are not as expected

Comment: The reliance on first name as a means to associate your subquery to the main query is prone to error.  What if multiple students have the same first name?  Even using first + last name is not a guarantee for uniqueness.  In other words, you should only make associations (and joins) on guaranteed unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your subselect you need to link both tables, for example by using an alias

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    subject_id,
    (SELECT 
            MAX(score)
        FROM
            cbt_attempts_tbl
        WHERE
            first_name = f1.first_name) AS MAX_SCORE
FROM
    cbt_attempts_tbl f1
WHERE
    score IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY first_name DESC
```

But I don't really know what you are searching for, but following give the same, as DISTINCT doesn't make sense as long you don't have multiple rows with the same subject_id and name combination

```
SELECT 
    first_name,
    last_name,
    subject_id,
    (SELECT 
            MAX(score)
        FROM
            cbt_attempts_tbl
        WHERE
            first_name = f1.first_name) AS MAX_SCORE
FROM
    cbt_attempts_tbl f1
WHERE
    score IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY first_name,
    last_name,
    subject_id
ORDER BY first_name DESC
```

Comment: Can you explain why a subquery is necessary?  Why not `MAX(score)` in the main query (with the required grouping also in the main query)?

Comment: Moreover, query would skip students those do not have any score by subject

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about students without any score , then your query would be like

`SELECT first_name, last_name, subject_id, MAX(score) FROM cbt_attempts_tbl GROUP BY first_name, last_name, subject_id ORDER BY first_name DESC`

Otherwise, if you want to keep a full student list, you need to make a left joined query like

`SELECT DISTINCT t.first_name, t.last_name, scores.subject_id, scores.subject_max_score FROM cbt_attempts_tbl t LEFT JOIN (SELECT first_name, last_name, subject_id, MAX(score) AS subject_max_score FROM cbt_attempts_tbl GROUP BY first_name, last_name, subject_id) scores ON scores.first_name = t.first_name AND scores.last_name = t.last_name GROUP BY t.first_name, t.last_name, scores.subject_id ORDER BY t.first_name DESC`

At last, if to be more comprehensive, your database design is not correct. You should have a `students` table and your `cbt_attempts_tbl` table should have a foreign key `student_id` that references a `students` table `id` column. And then it would be completely different query - select from students left joined by cbt_attempts_tbl on foreign key condition

Comment: join can be good, but subqueries in the SELECT helps, when you need the vaules from the SEELCT itself(they must be prior in the order) so that join will not work.

Comment: Join in this case will give you a full student list with max scores by subject, if they do have, or with null, if they do not

Comment: you asked why not use join and i pointed the cause, as i today faced the same problem

Comment: I did not asked why not to use join. In OP's case as he retrieves max scores all over the table, there will be no difference (maybe, and more likely join would be faster as it would be one table scan opposite n table scans on subquery, need to look an explain and query costs) between subquery and join in results